# Returning values from volley onResponse

Tags: java, android, object, android-volley

I am trying to make a more object oriented program with Volley. Currently I have the problem of not being able to extract data from inside the onResponse method of volley.

```
 private void getMember(String memberid){
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success"); //key["success"]
                String userid = jsonResponse.getString("userid");
                if(success){
                    byte[] decoded_img = Base64.decode(jsonResponse.getString("userpic"), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap member_pic = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decoded_img, 0, decoded_img.length);
                    FamMember member = new FamMember(jsonResponse.getString("username")); // creating new object

////// where I need to capture the image/ any data that I get in the Json response///
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LandingActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(member.username)
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                            .create()
                            .show(); //properly displays newly created object 'username'
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LandingActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Unable to Login")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    //HAPPENS AFTER RESPONSE HAS BEEN GIVEN FROM SERVER////////
    MemberRequest memberRequest = new MemberRequest(type,memberid,responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(LandingActivity.this);
    queue.add(memberRequest); //puts actual request into the queue for processing
}
```

I have to be able to get the response and use them as variables to pass into my activity. How do I go about doing this when I am given the error that I cannot have any returns on the methods above?

Comment: check whether response is null or it has something

Comment: it does return the appropriate response. I just need to get it out and use the data elsewhere in the code

Answer (score 2):

Create a new interface like this :

```
  public interface VolleyCallback {
            void onSuccess(String result);
            void onError(String result);
        }
```

Where you use callback interfaces :

```
 public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
      StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response);
            }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
               callback.onError(volleyError + "");
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext()).add(strReq);
      }
```

Use interface on your activity class like:

```
 FunctionName(new VolleyCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String result){
             ... //do stuff here
         }
         @Override
         public void onError(String result) {
             ... //show error here         
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Global variable outside of the Volley block

```
    public String response_var="";

    public void getMember()
    {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    {
 response_var=response;
    }

    }
```

Comment: There are some cases where this approach doesn't work, for example, when you are instantiating a Singleton class for Android Volley, and you have to wait for the finalization of the Volley Request, for that you can continue the other steps of your main class like, for example, to obtain the string stored at "response_var". 
For other situations (everything running at the same class, same block of code, and so forth), seems to works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Volley and other asynchronous HTTP libraries are well **asynchronous**. Your activity cannot directly get hold of the http response. You need to process the data with in the `onResponse` method and then communicate with the activity. One way is to send a local broadcast.

Comment: Do you have any example about "sending a local broadcast"? It is worth to mention some code, since that you are bringing a different approach (which is something great), in order to solve this problem. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that takes the response (or part of the response you want) as argument. For example:

```
private void processResponse(String encodedUserPic, String userName) {

    // Use the response as you need
    byte[] decodedImg = Base64.decode(encodedUserPic), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap memberPic = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedImg, 0, decodedImg.length);
    FamMember member = new FamMember(userName); 
}
```

Then, you can pass the response to this method from inside the onResponse method:

```
private void getMember(String memberid){
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success"); //key["success"]
            String userid = jsonResponse.getString("userid");

            if(success){
                String encodedUserPic = jsonResponse.getString("userpic");
                String userName = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                // Callback:
                processResponse(encodedUserPic, userName);
                ...
            }
            ...
```

Margin note: in Java, lower camelcase notation is the convention, instead of underscored.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: So if I follow this correctly, the callback method is able to take the data and move it outside the onResponse method? Will I be able to return the data from the callback so that I can use it in other parts of the program?

Comment: Exactly; then you can do anything you need with the response in the processResponse() method, and use it throughout your app.

Comment: Since the getMember() method is void and does not have a return, how would I be able to somehow return the resulting object that I've just created? I put the getMember() method outside but due to Volley onResponse() I can't have it return the object I created.

Comment: You won't be able to make getMember() return the object. The way to do it is to call getMember() and then process the response in the callback.

Maybe you can rename processResponse() as "onMemberReceived()" or something so that its function is clearer.